# Decode MIME email with python

Tags: python, email, mime

I am writing a script that needs to save some information out of an email.  I have cpanel setup on my webserver to pipe emails to a certain address to my python script.  I can see that the data is coming in correctly through,

```
email = sys.stdin.readlines()
```

but I cannot figure out how to decode it to see the different message parts.  I have read the python documentation on MIME, but have had no success decoding the messages.

How do I decode these MIME messages and access their different parts?

Answer (score 0):

have a look at the python [email](http://docs.python.org/2/library/email) module. [email.message_from_string()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/email.parser.html#email.message_from_string) is a good starting point. Be sure to call it with the full input from `sys.stdin` ( `read()` instead of `readlines()` ) . Once you have a Message object, you can have a look at the different parts using [email.message.Message.walk()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/email.message.html#email.message.Message.walk) for example.